# ¿Cómo generar terciles para una variable en R?

Tags: r

Tengo una variable intervalar que va de 1 a 5 (n=6341)
¿Cómo puedo recodificarla a terciles?
y luego, ¿cómo puedo recodificarla en terciles en orden ascendente, es decir, un tercil bajo, un tercil medio y un tercil alto?

De antemano gracias

Comment: No estoy seguro, algo así: `quantile(sample(1:5, 6341, replace=TRUE), seq(0, 1, 1/3))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como no tienes un vector, voy a crear un vector.

```
set.seed(2020)
x<-sample(1:5, 6301, T)
# Viendo los 6 primeros valores. 

head(x)
[1] 4 4 1 1 4 2
```

Entonces lo que sigue es conseguir los terciles de este vector, para lo cual se usa la función `quantile()`.

```
terciles<-quantile(x, probs = c(.33,.66,1))
```

Por último, recodificamos para que quede en terciles. Para lo cual usamos la función `cut()`.

```
x<-cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf,terciles), labels = c("1er tercil","2do tercil",
                                                 "3er tercil"))
```

Para ver el resultado podemos verlo a través de una tabla.

```
table(x)

1er tercil   2do tercil  3er tercil 
   2539         2552       1210
```

Tienes tu variable recodificada en terciles.

Comment: Perfecto maestro. Entiendo. ¿Y cómo hago para ordenarla en orden ascendente, es decir, tercil bajo, tercil medio, y tercil alto?. Intenté agregándole %>% arrange(asc(d.f$x)) . Pero me arroja un error
Error in UseMethod("arrange_") : 
  no applicable method for 'arrange_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: No necesitas ordenar porque para sacar los terciles la función `quantile` internamente lo ordena y luego lo divide en tres partes iguales.

Pero si quieres ordenarlo por tu cuenta usa la función `sort(x, decreasing=F)`